# Can Address Book still store local groups or contacts with iCloud enabled?

Tags: macos, contacts

I want to be able to keep a group of contacts on my Mac *only*, while keeping the rest of them synched to iCloud (as they currently do).

A bit of background: I'm wanting to do this since I'm dabbling with a bit of scripting involving the Address Book, and I want to be able to create test contacts without disrupting my real Address Book, and risking the wrath of the sync gods. My workaround has been using a second account that only has local storage, but it's disruptive having to switch accounts to test something.

The Address Book preferences has an *On My Mac* account listed alongside my iCloud account, but I don't see any options when creating new contacts or groups for putting them in local storage. If I reveal the groups pane, new groups get put under the iCloud section, and I don't see any local/On My Mac section.

Is the *On My Mac* account a mirage, not actually accessible if you have iCloud enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Mountain Lion solution that I hope works on Lion. (I just worked at this from the other way - [wanting to banish forever the **On My Mac** group](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83475/can-the-default-contact-store-for-mountain-lion-be-icloud).)

- Open Contacts
- Select On My Mac as the default account.
- Import a contact or two from a vCard or import your test data set from the **Import…** menu
- Switch back your default account to iCloud.

Going forward you can always drag a .vcf / vCard file into the **On My Mac** list to import there directly without changing the default account.

Comment: Nice, this appears to do what I was trying. I've switched to all 10.8 now, so I can't immediately check if it works for Lion as well (although I don't remember Lion having a default option).

Comment: Nice - we could edit the question and leave things up in the air for anyone still on Lion - your call on that. Glad it helped.