# Can the default contact store for Mountain Lion be iCloud?

Tags: icloud, contacts

I'm struggling to manage duplicate contacts and would like to entirely and permanently disable the "On My Mac" category for contacts.

I never, ever want a contact to be added to a Mac and not be stored in iCloud.

Have I missed a setup step since I'm ending up missing contacts on my iOS devices when my Mac decides to store things locally instead of globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a step when setting up iCloud.

On each Mac, you can set the default account to be iCloud in the general preferences.

[image: Contacts general preferences]

Now, you'll need a short clean up to migrate all your incorrectly filed contacts.

- Select Accounts and temporarily disable each iCloud / Exchange / online account.
- Then export all the "On My Mac" contacts to a vCard file and delete them *(you have a backup of your Mac and if paranoid, a full export of all contacts before you delete things, no?)*
- Once things are clean, enable the default account, check that it's set like above, and drag the contacts onto the "All bike@whatever"

[image]

- Import all the contacts, even if there are duplicates as you can then have Contacts look for duplicates and merge / update existing contacts as needed.
- Once you've deleted all contacts from **On My Mac** and deselected it as the default, Contacts should hide that group from view and simplify your contacts going forward.
- At this point, optionally enable other cloud contact sources and re-verify the default account.